# Check two drawable images

Tags: android

All

I have created frame animation using Animation drawable. I have 25 images in that animation. Now I have to compare Image which is the current frame in animation with the one that is stored in the res/drawable folder.

How to compare this two drawables?? == and .equals methods wont work with the drawables.

Please give me reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

you can provide id to the drawable image by using "imageview.setid" and try to compare that given id of images by using "imageview.getid"(use any int for id)

Answer (score -2):

if You want to compare two drawable then use following code

i.e :

```
drawable1 = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
drawable2 = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

if (drawable1.getConstantState().equals(drawable2.getConstantState())) 
{
  //write your code.
} else {
  //write your code.
}
```

Comment: This does not appear to work in my tests. Drawable.ConstantState doesn't override `equals`.